# Javascript changing several divs classes, tabbed content

Tags: javascript, tabs

I am making some tabbed content, I have the tabs inline and overlapping each other slightly, meaning they have three states: inactive tab ("it" class), active tab ("at" class) and trailing tab ("tt" class) which follows the active tab. In the code sample below, tab three is active and tab four is the trailing tab as it comes after it.

```
<div id="tabnest">
    <div id="tab" class="it"><a href="#" onclick="#">Tab One</a></div>
    <div id="tab" class="it"><a href="#" onclick="#">Tab Two</a></div>
    <div id="tab" class="at"><a href="#" onclick="#">Tab Three</a></div>
    <div id="tab" class="tt"><a href="#" onclick="#">Tab Four</a></div>
    <div id="tab" class="it"><a href="#" onclick="#">Tab Five</a></div><br>
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

I'm a total newbie to JavaScript I'd like each tab when clicked to:
1. change all the other tabs classes to "it",
2. change the current, clicked tab class to "at" and
3. change the next tabs class to "tt" if one exists.

From research on the net, I understand that these are the functions I want roughly:

```
document.getElementById('tab').nextSibling;
document.getElementById('tab').className = "it";
```

I just don't know how to call a function and stich it up together. Sorry for the complicatedness of this, if it's impossible to call the next div/tab and change its class solely then don't worry, could you just help me change the selected tabs class and all the others please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: using id with the same value is not the best way. Use `name` insstead.

Comment: is using jQuery an option? makes this type of thing very easy to do.

Comment: Also, id's should be unique. Try giving them a class of "tab", you can stack classes in the class attribute class="tt tab" class="at tab".

Comment: Does getElementByName call the Id? How would I stitch the two pieces of javascript together to form a function?

Comment: I'd rather not use a JavaScript Library if I'm honest. Ahh thank you Louis, I will certainly do that, it should make things easier when calling the next tab, if it's as simple as adding 1 to the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/E7jnq/1/ for a jQuery implementation, or http://jsfiddle.net/ryMH3/ for a vanilla JS implementation.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#tabnest a').click(function()
    {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('div').removeClass('at').removeClass('tt').addClass('it'); // Set everything to 'it'
        $(this).parent().addClass('at'); // Set this div to 'at'
        if ($(this).parent().next('div').length > 0)
        {
            $(this).parent().next('div').addClass('tt');
        }
    });
});
```

Vanilla JS:

```
var tabNest = document.getElementById('tabnest');
var tabs = getElementsByClassName('tab');


for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++)
{
    addEventListener(tabs[i], 'click', function ()
    {
        for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++)
        {
            if (tabs[i] == this)
                this.className = 'tab at';
            else if (tabs[i - 1] == this)
                tabs[i].className = 'tab tt';
            else
                tabs[i].className = 'tab it';
        }
        this.className = 'tab at';

    }, false);
}

function getElementsByClassName(classname, node)
{
    if(!node) node = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var a = [];
    var re = new RegExp('\\b' + classname + '\\b');
    var els = node.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for(var i=0,j=els.length; i<j; i++)
        if(re.test(els[i].className))
            a.push(els[i]);
    return a;
}

function addEventListener(element, eventType, handler, capture)
{
    if (element.addEventListener)
        element.addEventListener(eventType, handler, capture);
    else if (element.attachEvent)
        element.attachEvent("on" + eventType, handler);
}
```

Comment: Good solution if you use jQuery !!

Comment: It does make this kind of thing *much* easier. I can work on a plain JS version is the OP wants, but jQuery makes DOM traversal an absolute breeze.

Comment: Wow that is absolutely perfect, thank you so much Joe, that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Dan Just seen your comment further up about not wanting to use a JS Library - would you like me to work on one that just uses vanilla JS or is this OK with jQuery? :)

Comment: @Joe Oh I hadn't realised this uses jQuery, I mean it depends how complicated it would get, if very don't bother. If you could that would be great, if that's not too much of a hassle. I really need to get reading into JS because when I read it I can more or less understand what's going on but starting from scratch is a no go.

Comment: @Dan updated with a vanilla JS version. As you can see, it required the use of 2 other functions, getElementsByClassName (a very useful thing that natively, JS can't do) and addEventListener (a cross-browser version). If you at all can, I recommend learning jQuery - it handles all the cross-browser stuff, and all the "JS really should be able to [xyz] but it can't" stuff for you, letting you crack on with writing code :)

Comment: @Joe I might stick to jQuery that seemed to do the trick, plus it looks much neater and as you said it handles all the cross-browser compatibility so that's probably better as I don't know well this would function in environments such as IE6 :p The vanilla one seems to hide my current style applied to any of the tab divs, except while the mouse button is down, but it's okay. I think I'm going to settle for jQuery. Thank you for sending me both versions of the code, I will compare it to other code and see if I can do anything myself so I actually learn, but thank you - you've been great help (:

Comment: @Dan That's just because I assumed you had no other styles being applied, as in the first post :P It's possible to get around it using `.replace`, but really jQuery will stop you losing years of your life to stress :P If the question is solved, mind accepting the answer? :) In general on Stack, you should try to accept an answer for each question (assuming the answer is correct) as if you leave too many un-accepted questions, people will be less likely to answer you in future :)

Comment: @Joe absolutely, best answer, best help, thank you very much (:

Answer (score 1):

First, you cannot re-use an id.  An element id must be unique.  Use class for that.  I would suggest giving each tab a class of `tab` always.  Then give the active tag an additional class of "active" and for the trailing tab, use the adjacent sibling selector (`+`).  Ie, `.active + .tab`.

This is a great place to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).  The jQuery syntax would be:

```
$(function() {
    $(".tab").click(function () {
        $(".tab.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Drop that code into any script tag, and it'll just work.  If you don't want jQuery:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var tabNest = document.getElementById("tabNest");
    var tabs = tabNest.children;
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        tabs[i].onclick = tabClick;
    }
    function tabClick (e) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            tabs[i].className = tabs[i].className.replace(/\bactive\b/, "")
        }
        this.className += " active";
    }
};
```

Comment: What would be the ID of these divs then, just tab1, tab2, etc?

Comment: Why do they need an id?  If they do indeed need ids, id them sematically.  Eg, if your tab is for groceries, give it an id of "groceriesTab".

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

HTML :

```
<div id="tabnest">
    <div name="tab" class="it"><a href="#" onclick="#">Tab One</a></div>
    <div name="tab" class="it"><a href="#" onclick="#">Tab Two</a></div>
    <div name="tab" class="at"><a href="#" onclick="#">Tab Three</a></div>
    <div name="tab" class="tt"><a href="#" onclick="#">Tab Four</a></div>
    <div name="tab" class="it"><a href="#" onclick="#">Tab Five</a></div><br>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var atags = document.getElementsByName('tab'); //returns the array of all the element with tab as the name

for(var x=0; x<atags.length; x++){ // loops throught all the element with the name = tab
  // some code
  atags[x].className = "it";
}
```

Comment: would i place this between <script language="javascript"></script> in the head?

Comment: The javascript part goes between the `<script>` tags. Theses tags can be place in the `<head>` in deed.

Comment: @Dan S edit my solution. I did not illustrate how to use the loop. Now I do.

Comment: thank you for all your help, I will use this to help me understand JS more (:

Comment: @David - there is no `document.getElementByTagName` (singular).  I think you want `document.getElementsByName`, but that won't work for divs according to the [remarks of the documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536438(VS.85).aspx) since `name` is not an attribute of div.

Comment: @gilly3  Thanks, my memory did not serve me well on this one. `getElementByTagName` is use to access the dom element the the `name` attribute in the tag. Thanks for pointing that out.